# Extraer valor de datagridview (generado mediante SELECT) para integrarlo en TEXTBOX

Tags: c#

[image: Error]

Intento extraer el valor de Row para agregarlo al Textbox.

De ante mano agradezco.

Comment: Hola Daniel. Es importante que en lugar de una imagen, copies y pegues el código aqui. Lee [una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/)

Answer (score 3):

En primer lugar, la colección [`Rows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows(v=vs.110).aspx) de `DataGridView`  es una colección de tipo [`DataGridViewRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow(v=vs.110).aspx). Esto significa que cuando tu obtienes el valor `dgvVentaFinal.Rows[2]`, estas obteniendo una `DataGridViewRow`, es decir, toda una fila del grid. Obviamente, ese tipo no puede convertirse a `Int32`.

Para obtener un valor, debes especificar en que fila está,pero también en que celda (`Cell`), con lo que tienes que acceder de la siguiente manera:

```
dgvVentaFinal.Rows[2].Cells[0]
```

De esta manera accedes a la fila 2, columna 0. Pero aún así,lo que obtienes es un valor de tipo [`DataGridViewCell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell(v=vs.110).aspx), es decir, accedes a la celda (que tiene muchas propiedades), pero no a su valor. Para acceder al valor, debes obtener la propiedad `Value` de `DataGridViewCell`:

```
dgvVentaFinal.Rows[2].Cells[0].Value
```

Ahora si tienes el valor. Otra cosa extraña es que haces una conversión a `Int32` cuando lo que vas a hacer es mostrar el valor en un `TextBox`, con lo que se producirá una conversión implícita. Así que finalmente tu código debe ser el siguiente:

```
txtSubTotal.Text = dgvVentaFinal.Rows[2].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Pero.. pero.. es una imagen ;)